# Minted: Is there a Unicode/non-ASCII character that works for escapeinside?

Tags: symbols, unicode, minted

Documentation for `fancyvrb` and `minted` warn that users should not expect any character to work in a listing that would not work in `verbatim`. But they don't foreclose on the possibility, and the idea of using an escape character that would never appear in source code is a tantalizing prospect: juggling escape characters is a nuisance; much better is to set one and forget it.

I'd been using `listings` until a few days ago, when I discovered that `\lstinline` has problems in vertical mode (e.g. `\parbox`) that I understand `minted` does not have. And yet `listings` has the advantage that it allows escaping to LaTeX with non-ASCII characters—I've been using “`©`” without trouble—whereas `minted` hasn't accepted any of the dozen or so non-ASCII characters I've tried with `escapeinside` so far.

Does one exist?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=©©]{postgres}
  SELECT ©\(a ∈ A\)©
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

I'm compiling with `lualatex`, if that matters, with option `--shell-escape` and have Pygments version 2.2.0 installed and functioning.

Answer (score 3):

`escapeinside` can work with non-ASCII characters. But only if you can avoid encoding issues.

The `escapeinside` characters are passed to Python and Pygments as part of a `pygmentize` command that is executed via shell escape.  This fails under Windows because the characters are encoded as `utf8`, but by default Python interprets the `pygmentize` command arguments (`sys.argv`) as `cp1252` (at least with PowerShell).  Under Linux, it also fails, and the `©` is turning into the Unicode sequence `\udcc2\udca9`.  I'm not sure what set of encoding issues led to this, since everything seems to be `utf8` by default.

If you can get everything using the same encoding, then it will work (I tried editing Pygments' `cmdline.py` to force `utf8` under Windows), but getting that to happen may be difficult in some cases.

Comment: From G. Poore himself! Amazing—thank you. Encoding's in that infinite set of things I know shit-all about, but an authority's finger pointing that way is a great start. I'm on a Linux system (most recent Debian stable, "Stretch"), if there's anything else you might suggest.

Comment: @LaTeX2enub1336 I can't suggest anything for Linux, because I'm still not sure what is happening there. I'm working on plans for `minted` 3.0, and it will likely take a different approach to option handling that will avoid these sorts of issues. So non-ASCII `escapeinside` will probably work eventually without needing to worry about encodings.

Comment: Appreciate your work very much. I've been familiarizing myself with cmdline.py and with Pygments more generally since last night. Integrating it with LaTeX as a listings package was a great idea and makes yours a clear winner. I look forward to the new release.